# Unix or linux segmentation error

Tags: shell-script

While running program i got coredump error.but in my source coredump file is not reflecting.please tell me where to see core dump file names.

Comment: What Unix are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` should help you derive the corefile location.

Ex:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
/corefiles/%u/core-%e-%p-%t
```

Therefore corefiles are in a directory by the real user id of dumped process inside corefiles directory in root(/). For a more comprehensive understanding: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html